# Integration by parts for the tensor

Tags: integration, tensors, finite-element-method

I am using FEM to solve a pressure equation for a compressible flow. To obtain the weak form I am stuck at how to integrate by parts the following term:

$\int_{\Omega}P \mathbb{K}:\nabla(\nabla P)d\Omega $

Here, 'P' is a scalar (Pressure) and '$\mathbb{K}$' is a 2nd order tensor of permeability for a material.
I have to integrate it by parts to reduce the order of the derivative operator, such that I can define my functional spaces of solution appropriately.

This tensor term $\nabla(\nabla P)$ is creating a problem. I tried to look for a tensor identity to simplify it but I can't find anything helpful. Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: Is the term supposed to be non-linear? If that's so, why do you want to reduce the number of derivatives?

Comment: Yes that is a non-linear term. If i don't integrate by parts then how will i solve using FEM because i am taking my solution space to be in $H^{1}$, are you suggesting I should take high oder soblev space to define my solution. If so then how do i proced to solve this using FEM? the non-linear term is creating an issue for me

Comment: Probably you first want to linearize the term somehow (e.g. Newton's or fixed point iteration) and only afterwards integrate by parts.

Comment: Can you recommend a reference text where i can find such example? I know the method and how it works but when applying it i get confused. Thank you for the help

Comment: Before doing anything, you should include the test function somewhere inside the integral. I cannot help you any further unless you provide the NPDE you are trying to solve.

Comment: The PDE is: $\int_{\Omega} {p}^{*} \cdot\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}d\Omega = \frac{1}{\phi \mu}\int_{\Omega}p^{*} \big[\nabla P\cdot(\mathbb{K}\cdot\nabla P)+P\mathbb{K}:\nabla(\nabla P)\big]d\Omega \hspace{5mm}$ ,,,,,.....Here, P$\rightarrow$ Pressure (scalar field), $\mathbb{K}\rightarrow$ Permeability tensor of material, $\phi\rightarrow$ Porosity(constant) and $\mu\rightarrow$ Viscosity(constant), $p{*}$ are the test functions.

Comment: Are you using an implicit Euler discretization in time? How are you coping with the first term on the right hand side since that is also nonlinear?

Comment: I have to solve for both transient and steady case. Currently i m trying to solve the steady case thus $\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}=0$. For the transient case i was thinking explicit Euler discretization in time would be easier to use since then i won't have to linearise the terms, what  would you recommend for transient case? But anyway i have to linearise for steady case, so please help me with the linearisation.

Comment: Implicit Euler would be my first try. If this doesn't work, then Crank-Nicholson. Explicit Euler usually fails to conserve necessary quantities and the preservation of the required boundary conditions can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I denote the solution by $p$ and the test function by $q$. Moreover, the components of the permeability tensor I denote by $K_{ij}$. Using the index notation, the steady state problem reads
$$
\int_\Omega p_{,i} K_{ij} p_{,j}q \,\mathrm{d}x + \int_\Omega p K_{ij} p_{,ij} q \,\mathrm{d}x = 0.
$$
Let me perform a direct linearization of this form. For obtaining the Newton's method, we can simply substitute $p = p_0 + \delta p$ where $p_0$ is the initial guess and $\delta p$ is the new unknown (a perturbation towards the true solution). In Newton's method, the higher order terms with $(\delta p)^2$ are approximated with zero.

If I computed correctly, a single step of the Newton's iteration corresponds to: find $\delta p$ such that
$$
\int_\Omega (\delta p)_{,i} K_{ij} (p_0)_{,j} q \,\mathrm{d}x + \int_\Omega (p_0)_{,i} K_{ij} (\delta p)_{,j} q \,\mathrm{d}x +
\int_\Omega \delta p K_{ij} (p_0)_{,ij} q \,\mathrm{d}x\\
+\int_\Omega p_0 K_{ij} (\delta p)_{,ij} q \,\mathrm{d}x = - \int_\Omega (p_0)_{,i} K_{ij} (p_0)_{,j} q \,\mathrm{d}x-\int_\Omega p_0 K_{ij} (p_0)_{,ij} q \,\mathrm{d}x,
$$
for every test function $q$. Note that you might be able to simplify the expressions if $K_{ij}$ has some properties like symmetry.

Now you can use Green's formulae on the annoying terms like the fourth term on the left hand side. E.g.
$$
\int_\Omega p_0 K_{ij} (\delta p)_{,ij} q \,\mathrm{d}x = - \int_{\Omega} (p_0 q)_{,j} K_{ij} (\delta p)_{,i} \,\mathrm{d}x \quad \text{(+ possible boundary terms.)}
$$

Thus, you start with an initial guess $p_0$ and compute the perturbation $\delta p$. Then you get a new initial guess from $p_0 + \delta p$. Do this repeatedly as long as $\delta p$ is small (in some appropriate norm).

Comment: Can we use Green's formula for this term you mentioned?, Since it's not the divergence but gradient of gradient. $\int_{\Omega} p_{0}K_{ij} \nabla(\nabla \delta p)q dx$

Comment: In component form, this is just the usual "1D integration by parts" formula from standard calculus. This can be used to derive all sorts of Green-type formulae.

Comment: In 1D i can understand but since i mentioned that my problem is in 2D i.e. $\Omega\in$ x and y, so, $\int_{\Omega x}\int_{\Omega y}p_{0}K_{ij}\nabla(\nabla \delta p)q\hspace{1mm}dxdy$, this term is bothering me,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,I am sorry i am asking a lot of questions but i am still a bit confused

Comment: No problem. If you happen to take a course in continuum mechanics, it is typically one of the first exercises to derive 2D/3D Green-type formulae starting from the classical 1D integration-by-parts formula. For arbitrary scalar functions $a$ and $b$, you have $\int_\Omega a b_{,i} \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{\partial \Omega} ab n_i - \int_\Omega a_{,i}b\,\mathrm{d}x$. When deriving multidimensional formulae, the idea is to use component notation and work on single dimension/partial derivative at a time using this simple scalar formula.